# how to sort Multi dimesional array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Hello I have array like :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Product_1
            [1] => Gold
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Product_1
            [1] => Silver
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Product_1
            [1] => Black
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Product_1
            [1] => Red
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Product_2
            [1] => Silver
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Product_2
            [1] => Gold
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => Product_2
            [1] => Black
        )
```

How can I sort this array into

```
[Product_1] => Array
          ( 
            [0] Silver
            [1] Black
            [2] Red
          )
[Product_2] => Array
          (
            [0] Silver
            [1] Gold
            [2] Black
          )
```

Can someone help?

Comment: I suggest that you make an attempt, then show us what you tried and what specifically went wrong.

Comment: What happened to Product_1/Gold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop through your `$array` and push each color value to a `$result` array having the product name as the key.

```
$array = [
    ['Product_1', 'Gold'],
    ['Product_1', 'Silver'],
    ['Product_1', 'Black'],
    ['Product_1', 'Red'],
    ['Product_2', 'Silver'],
    ['Product_2', 'Gold'],
    ['Product_2', 'Black'],
];

$result = [];

foreach ($array as $values) {
    list ($product, $color) = $values;
    $result[$product][] = $color;
}

print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [Product_1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Gold
            [1] => Silver
            [2] => Black
            [3] => Red
        )

    [Product_2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Silver
            [1] => Gold
            [2] => Black
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can simply use `array_walk` as

```
$result = [];
array_walk($array,function($v,$k)use(&$result){$result[$v[0]][] = $v[1];});
print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [Product_1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Gold
            [1] => Silver
            [2] => Black
            [3] => Red
        )

    [Product_2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Silver
            [1] => Gold
            [2] => Black
        )

)
```